# Issue deleting many to many collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables - QuestionOptions and Answers. There's a many to many relationship between the two. I'm trying to remove QuestionOptions pertaining to a specific Question, and need to remove the answers first. Here's my code:

```
using (Survey_Context _context = new Survey_Context())
{
    IQueryable<QuestionOption> questionOptions = _context.QuestionOptions.Where(qo => qo.QuestionID == questionID);
    foreach (QuestionOption questionOption in questionOptions.ToList())
    {
        foreach (Answer answer in questionOption.Answers)
            questionOption.Answers.Remove(answer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    _context.QuestionOptions.RemoveRange(questionOptions.ToList());
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This causes the following:

> Error - System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified;
>   enumeration operation may not execute.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure if this is what is causing the issue, but when you query the `questionOptions` I would put it to a list then. so `List<QuestionOption> questionOptions = _context.QuestionOptions.Where(qo => qo.QuestionID == questionID).ToList()` and then you can remove the `.ToList()` from each of the `questionOptions`

Comment: That was actually my original code, and it caused the same error.

Comment: `questionOption.Answers.Remove(answer);` to `_context.Answers.Remove(answer);`. If that doesn't work please post what line you are getting the error at.

Comment: Also wanted to note you could remove the `foreach` loop and do this instead `_context.Answers.RemoveRange(questionOption.Answers);` Not 100% sure but I believe you should gain some performance by doing it this way as well.

Comment: Please let me know if any of those work for you and I shall post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems in your code.

First, the error that is causing the Invalid Operation Exception you are seeing :

You are trying to remove element of a list that you are iterating on !

You should not modify a list (I mean : add or delete elements) that you are enumerating (with a foreach, like in your code) .

That is simply not valid this way.

Second, there is an error of logic :

If you want to delete elements, then you want to delete this objects from the *database context*, not remove them from some list that you just created.

As suggested in comments, you can correct both of these errors in one go by replacing :

```
foreach (Answer answer in questionOption.Answers)
    questionOption.Answers.Remove(answer);
```

by

```
_context.Answers.RemoveRange(questionOption.Answers);
```

Comment: This not only explained my misgiving, but solved my problem. Thank you!